# Why is $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{1+x^{1/3}} dx = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{3(u-1)^2}{u} du$?

Tags: integration

When calculating the value of an integral via u-substitution, why are the following integral equivalent?

$$\int_{0}^{1} \dfrac{1}{1+x^{\frac{1}{3}}} dx = \int_{0}^{1} \dfrac{3(u-1)^2}{u} du$$

---

Progress so far:

\begin{align*}
u &= 1+ x^\frac{1}{3} \\
\frac{du}{dx} &= \dfrac{1}{3x^{\frac{2}{3}}} \\
dx &= 3x^{\frac{2}{3}}
\end{align*}

The critical step I do not understand is why $dx$ is being written as $3(u-1)^2$

Edit: My guess is that there is another substitution taking place, but I can't see it.

Comment: Take the first equation and solve it for $x$ (Or better yet, solve for $x^{2/3}$). When you substitute in, you’ll probably see why.

Comment: @Clayton wow, how daft of me. Thanks. Solved.

Comment: @Clayton since you were the first to point this out, and in such a way that I could recognize my problem myself, I will accept a solution from you if you post one.

Comment: No `\dfrac` in titles please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you can't have variable x on both sides.

$u=1+x^{\frac{1}{3}} \\ x^{\frac{1}{3}}=u-1 \\ x=(u-1)^{3} \\ dx=3(u-1)^2 du$.